# How can I use errorbar=('ci', False)?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

```
---Skip code---
fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(22, 10))
seasonal_plot(X.loc['2017'], y='sales', period="week", freq="day", ax=ax0)
ax0.set_title('Seasonal Plot (week/day) 2017')
seasonal_plot(X, y="sales", period="year", freq="dayofyear", ax=ax1);
ax1.set_title('Seasonal Plot (year/dayofyear)')
```

When you I the above code, the graph displays fine, but I get the following warning.

```
The `ci` parameter is deprecated. Use `errorbar=('ci', False)` for the same effect.
```

So, I checked seaborn's official website and it looks like it was changed in v0.12.0.

I've applied `errorbar=('ci', False)` in every way I can think of, but it just throws an error and won't output the graph.

How can I get the graph to print correctly without giving me a warning?

Thank you for reading this question.

Blessings to you.

More info. seasonal_plot is

```
def seasonal_plot(X, y, period, freq, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        _, ax = plt.subplots()
    palette = sns.color_palette("husl", n_colors=X[period].nunique(),)
    ax = sns.lineplot(
        x=freq,
        y=y,
        hue=period,
        data=X,
        ci=False,
        ax=ax,
        palette=palette,
        legend=False,
    )
    for line, name in zip(ax.lines, X[period].unique()):
        y_ = line.get_ydata()[-1]
        ax.annotate(
            name,
            xy=(1, y_),
            xytext=(6, 0),
            color=line.get_color(),
            xycoords=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
            textcoords="offset points",
            size=14,
            va="center",
        )
    return ax
```

Comment: What is `seasonal_plot`?

Comment: Entered additional information.

Answer (score 1):

`errorbar="ci"` alone should do the trick  (`errorbar=('ci', False)` does not show any confidence interval), tested both with seaborn 0.12.2 and 0.13.0.

Does the following minimal example work on your machine? If so, try to work your way up from this example to your version.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

sns.lineplot(
    data=data,
    x="carat",
    y="price",
    errorbar="ci",
)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ci=False` was never a valid argument; if you look at the docs for seaborn v0.11, you'll see

```
ci: int or “sd” or None
    Size of the confidence interval to draw when aggregating
    with an estimator. “sd” means to draw the standard deviation
    of the data. Setting to None will skip bootstrapping.
```

However, because `False` can be interpreted as `0` in many Python contexts, it didn't error but simply computed a 0% CI for you. What you probably wanted was `ci=None`, and you can analogously use `errorbar=None` in 0.12+.